# Opposite of to be green with envy

Tags: idioms

What's opposite way to say "**to be green with envy**" which to say to be happy about someone's success let's to say so.
Or is there some idioms for that matter?

Comment: First you need to find the word(s) that are the opposite of "envy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what is meant by "opposite"... "Red with rage"? "White with terror?" As for happy at someone's success, "delight in your success", "brag of her son's success", but the *single* word that best fits, I feel, is ["kvell"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/kvell), a Yiddish word that has been adopted into English.

If you look at the [definition of "kvell"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/kvell), it seems to suit your need precisely, i.e., glorying in the success of *someone else*.

Comment: But can green be replaced by another color still meaning to be happy about one's success? I'm asking it cause in my language there is.

Comment: Not that I know of. *Sanguine* can mean positive or positively expectant, and the etymology is from blood-red, as jocular characters might be described (https://www.etymonline.com/word/sanguine),  but it does not mean pleasure at *the success of someone else.* BTW, I *kvell* when a student passes a difficult test.